# onActivityResult data is null for web search

Tags: android, onactivityresult

My data is returning null for some reason after the I perform a web search. What I am trying to do, and I am not 100% sure if I am on the right track, is to grab all of the possible links from a web search. So if the user types in say "Java", my onActivityResult should be able to find all the links associated with the serach "Java", but right now my data is null.

Here is what I have:

```
public void onSearchClick(View v) {

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        String term = editTextInput.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, term);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SEARCH);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FAILED TO CONNECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SEARCH: {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                ArrayList<String> urls = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

                for(int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++){
                    System.out.println("************** " + urls.get(i));
                }
            }
            else if(data == null){//goes here
                System.out.println("null***********");
            }
            break;
        }

    }
```

If it helps, here is what I do when I run the program:

- type in something for the edit text
- press a button which does a web search for the content of the edit text
- once I reach the google search results, I press the back button, which leads me back to the first screen
- the results are then displayed, in this case NULL

Comment: make sure you have internet permission defined in your mainfest

Comment: @dex I do, I put the permission right above <application>